# How to add vertical spacing between UIfields using autolayouts in Ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

layouts and i want to give vertical spacing b/w "phoneNumber" to "appointment" labels
And
"phoneButton" to "appointment" labels   like see below my code

for this i have written two lines of code i think it should possible to write in one line for giving same vertical space from one label to multiple labels

please help me some one

### my code:-

```
 [Cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[appointment(30)]-5-[phoneNumber(30)]"
                                                                                 options:0
                                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                                   views:viewsDic]];

 [Cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[appointment(30)]-5-[phoneButton(30)]"
                                                                                 options:0
                                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                                   views:viewsDic]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Cartography](https://github.com/robb/Cartography). It will make layouts much much easier for you. Using this, if you want to add vertical gap of 10, you can do it like this

```
constrain(appointment, phoneNumber, phoneButton) { view1, view2, view3 in
    view2.top == view1.bottom + 5
    view3.top == view1.bottom + 5
}
```

Comment: i dont know about catography please explain clearly because i am very begginer

Comment: @Ramakrishna sorry I forgot to add the link earlier. Now updated. Import Cartography to your project, and put the code in. Aso, there are others constraints that you would need to add to make it work. This are only y-axis constraints, you need to add x-axis constraints as well.

Comment: i want solution in objc and i don't know swift well and just say how to full fill my above requirement in objc

Comment: @Ramakrishna Please add the requirement to your question and instead of `swift` tag, use `objective-c` tag.

Comment: if you know objectice please help me how should i solve this issue